# Padding in structures in C

Tags: c, structure, padding

This is an interview question. Till now, I used to think such questions were purely compiler dependent and shouldn't worry me, but now, I am rather curious about it.

Suppose you are given two structures as:

```
struct A {  
  int* a;  
  char b;  
 }
```

and ,

```
struct B {  
  char a;  
  int* b;  
}
```

So which one would you prefer and why? 
My answer went like this (though I was somewhat shooting in the dark) that the first structure should be preferred since the compiler allocates space for a structure in some multiples of the word size (which is the size of the pointer - 4 bytes on 32 bit machines and 8 bytes on 64 bit ones). So, for both the structures the compiler would allocate 8 bytes(assuming its a 32 bit machine). But, in the first case, the padding would be done after all my variables(i.e. after a and b). So even if by some chance, b gets some value that overflows and destroys my next padded bytes, but my a is still safe.

He didn't seemed much pleased and asked for one disadvantage of the first structure over the second. I didn't have much to say. :D

Please help me with the answers.

Comment: The only slight advantage I can think of is if you add more char fields later, then with first one you can just add them at the end without introducing additional padding.  Other than that, it seems to me like a trick question to see if you are confident enough to insist there is no advantage.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "overflows and destroys my next padded bytes". Are you worried about a stack overflow, or simply exceeding the capacity of a char?

Comment: @chris: If you exceed the capacity of a char, it simply winds around.. I meant buffer overflow.. I didnt actually think much about it.. :D

Comment: I am guessing that this might be related to the placement of the char in the machine word. The C Spec does not guarantee that a char will be mapped to the first byte of a memory word so it could also be mapped to the last byte of the machine word, thus creating an advantage for either of the structs.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't think there's an advantage for any of this structures. There is one(!) constant in this equation. The order of the members of the struct is guaranteed to be as declared.

So in case like the following, the second structure **might** have an advantage, since it probably has a smaller size, but not in your example, as they will probably have the same size:

```
struct {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
} X;
```

Vs.

```
struct {
    char a;
    char b;
    int c;
} Y;
```

**A little more explanation regarding comments below:**

All the below is not a 100%, but the common way the structs will be constructed in 32 bits system where int is 32 bits:

Struct X:

```
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 char  pad    pad   pad   ---------int---------- char   pad   pad   pad   = 12 bytes
```

struct Y:

```
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 char  char  pad   pad   ---------int----------        = 8 bytes
```

Comment: Yea thats what @kevin beck hinted at in his comment... :)

Comment: would u please care to explain why 1st one will have smaller size.. i found other way around in my compiler..

Comment: @Shashi Bhushan - You're right, I had a typo and I wrote it wrong, the 2nd is the smaller, my bad...

Comment: @MByD: he second is probably just as large, since there will be padding at the end so that, when there are two or more of them in an array, members will still be aligned on their natural boundaries, and not just the first one.

Comment: @MByD: I now see why you didn't agree. I was talking about the two structs in the original question, and not yours. I missed the "following" in your text. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis - I made a bad choice by calling them A and B :)

Comment: @MByD: There's another guarantee: there can be no padding before the first member.

Comment: @MByD, If the padding happens, what is filled with in those padded spaces?Content of those padded spaces?

Answer (score 11):

Some machines [access data more efficiently](http://c-faq.com/struct/padding.html) when the values aligned to some boundary. Some [*require*](http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/ptralign.html) data to be aligned.

> On modern 32-bit machines like the SPARC or the Intel [34]86, or any
>   Motorola chip from the 68020 up, each data iten must usually be
>   ``self-aligned'', beginning on an address that is a multiple of its
>   type size. **Thus, 32-bit types must begin on a 32-bit boundary, 16-bit
>   types on a 16-bit boundary, 8-bit types may begin anywhere**,
>   struct/array/union types have the alignment of their most restrictive
>   member.

So you could have

```
struct B {  
    char a;
    /* 3 bytes of padding ? More ? */
    int* b;
}
```

> A simple rule that minimize padding in the ``self-aligned'' case (and
>   does no harm in most others) is to order your struct members by
>   decreasing size.

Personally I see not disadvantage with the first struct when compared to the second.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a disadvantage of the first structure over the second in this particular case, but it's possible to come up with examples where there are disadvantages to the general rule of putting the largest members first:

```
struct A {  
    int* a;
    short b;
    A(short num) : b(2*num+1), a(new int[b]) {} 
    // OOPS, `b` is used uninitialized, and a good compiler will warn. 
    // The only way to get `b` initialized before `a` is to declare 
    // it first in the class, or of course we could repeat `2*num+1`.
}
```

I also heard about quite a complicated case for large structs, where the CPU has fast addressing modes for accessing pointer+offset, for small values of offset (up to 8 bits, for example, or some other limit of an immediate value). You best micro-optimize a large structure by putting as many of the most commonly-used fields as possible within range of the fastest instructions.

The CPU might even have fast addressing for pointer+offset and pointer+4*offset. Then suppose you had 64 char fields and 64 int fields: if you put the char fields first then all fields of both types can be addressed using the best instructions, whereas if you put the int fields first then the char fields that aren't 4-aligned will just have to be accessed differently, perhaps by loading a constant into a register rather than with an immediate value, because they're outside the 256-byte limit.

Never had to do it myself, and for instance x86 allows big immediate values anyway. It's not the sort of optimization that anyone would normally think about unless they spend a lot of time staring at assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, there's no advantage in choosing either *in the general case*. The only situation where the choice would matter in practice is if *structure packing is enabled*, in the case `struct A` would be a better choice (since both fields would be aligned in memory, while in `struct B` the `b` field would be located at an odd offset). Structure packing means that no padding bytes are inserted inside the structure.

However, this is a rather uncommon scenario: structure packing is generally only enabled in specific situations. It is not a concern on most programs. And it is also not controllable through any portable construction in the C standard.

Comment: +1, no assumptions/constraints about alignment were given in the question, so this would be a reasonable argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is also something of a guess, but most compilers have a misalign option that will explicitly not add padding bytes. This then requires (on some platforms) a runtime fixup (hardware trap) to align accesses on the fly (with corresponding performance penalty). If I remember right HPUX fell into this category. So the first struct the fields are still aligned even when misalign compiler options are used (because as you said the padding would be at the end).

Comment: While most compilers do indeed have an option for unaligned structures, usually they will not use a trap - it's cheaper to do a byte-by-byte copy to the stack, then an aligned read from there. Additionally, on some platforms (particularly x86), unaligned accesses can be done with minimal overhead natively (there is _some_ overhead however, but no trap, and problems with read/write tearing on SMP).